# How to Use Multiple Second List Level Styles in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In MS Word 2010, I have a numbered list.  The first time I want to use a second level, I want it to be bulleted.  The second time, I want it to be a second numbered list.  I want it to be something akin to:

> 1. Some stuff
>
>    - My
>    - second
>    - level
> 2. Some more stuff
>
>    1. My other
>    2. second
>    3. level

However, whenever I try to change the style of one second level, the style of the other one changes to match it.

One solution is to make one second level to be in fact a third level, and then change the indentation to match the second level, but as a purist, I'd much rather not.  Plus I'd like to level up my Office-fu.

Is there a good way to do this, to convince Word that the first level needs to be a single list, but the second levels are separate lists from each other?

Answer (score 0):

What I do (in Microsoft Word 2007) is

- go to the Styles dialog box
- click on “Options…”
- Select styles to show: “All styles”
- then use the styles that you want for list type and level.

In your example, it would be:

> 1. List Number
>
>    - List Bullet 2
>    - List Bullet 2
>    - List Bullet 2
> 2. List Number
>
>    1. List Number 2
>    2. List Number 2
>    3. List Number 2

Answer (score -1):

**This worked for me https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/creating_a_multilevel_list.html**

> To create a multilevel list, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Type your
>    list, and then select it.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
> On the Home tab, in the Paragraph group, click the Multilevel List
> button: (Fig.1)
>  You can find different styles by clicking the
> arrow next to Multilevel List on the Home tab, in the Paragraph group:
> (Fig.2)
>
> Create a numbered or bulleted list (see Creating
> numbered lists) and then:
>
> - Press Tab - Word indents a level in
>   the list
> - Press Shift+Tab - Word outdents a level in the
>   list.
>
> To add additional numbered
> items to your list, move the insertion point to the end of a line
> formatted with a number and press Enter. To stop entering items in the
> list, press Enter twice.
>
> Move the insertion point to the end
> of the last numbered item in your list. Press Enter and then Del, or
> press Enter and click the Numbering button on the Home tab, in the
> Paragraph group, to turn off the number formatting.
>
> Fig.1
>  [image]
>
> Fig.2
>  [image]