# Changing numbering styles on the same level

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Suppose I have a document that has multiple levels for numbering, but I want the style on the same level to be different. How can I achieve this?

> [image]

For example, the a, b, c, under 2), I want it to be roman letters, such as i, ii, iii. When I attempt the change the style, it changes all the second level styles.

I've already enabled show all styles, and changed the style manually, but then it doesn't keep the alignment the same. I know I can also manually change the alignment too, but I'd rather see if there's a way to do what I've described above.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to Use Multiple Second List Level Styles in Microsoft Word](http://superuser.com/q/859317/354511).

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same alignment, highlight the contents of a, b, and c for number 2, and either:

A) Go the the Numbers icon, click the drop down arrow, and choose "Define new number format". In the box for "Number style", choose the Roman Numerals case of your choice (lowercase or uppercase)

OR

B) Right click on the contents of a, b, and c, go to "Numbering", and choose the Roman Numerals that states Number alignment: left (though I only see that option for the lowercase roman numerals.)