# Microsoft Word: List inside a multi level list

Tags: microsoft-word, list

How do i make a normal list inside a multi level list? [Instead of following the parent list..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwCmL.png)
I'd like it to be like:

1. How to open a door
2. Opening a door

   2.1 First identify what door it is:

   ```
    1) A revolving door
    2) A trap door
    3) Not a door
   ```
3. CLOSING A DOOR

   3.1 Lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0):

Oops, seems like i found the [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/859317/how-to-use-multiple-second-list-level-styles-in-microsoft-word?rq=1). Create a new style, change it to a numbering style and apply to the nested list.